# Can't show input method words candidate box in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea editor, the input method box can't show.

This is ok in stackoverflow editor.

[image]

Comment: Please check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-412.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with the jdk8-121 will be ok.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-412